# Create alias for conditions in Drools Decision table

Tags: jboss, drools, drools-guvnor

Attached is my decision table, where in I'm using **sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get("SV202-02")** several times in my condition. 
 
Is there any way that we can create an alias for **sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get("SV202-02")** (for example, S) and use that alias in my condition instead of using the entire line every time?[image]

CONDITION
sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value >= '70010' && sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value <= '76499' || sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value >= '76506' && sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value <= '76999' || sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value >= '77001' && sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value <= '77032' || sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value >= '77051' && sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value <= '77059' || sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value >= '77071' && sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value <= '77084' || sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value >= '77261' && sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value <= '77999' || sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value >= '78000' && sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value <= '79999'

where sv2 is the object and SV2 is the class

Comment: The basic problem appears to be that you are expanding relatively simple data into code. There is no such abbreviation that I know.

Comment: I tried to reduce the code little bit as below: sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value >= '70010' &&  <= '76499' || sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get(""SV202-02"").Value >= '76506' &&  <= '76999' and it worked. But I wanted to know if there is any thing more we can reduce here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use an alias. Change your condition to:

`$s : sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get("SV202-02").Value >= '70010' && $s <= '76499' || 
    $s >= '76506' && $s <= '76999' || 
    $s >= '77001' && $s <= '77032' || 
    $s >= '77051' && $s <= '77059' || 
    $s >= '77071' && $s <= '77084' || 
    $s >= '77261' && $s <= '77999' || 
    $s >= '78000' && $s <= '79999'`

Comment: I'm getting below error: text=Variables can not be used inside bindings.
   text=Field Reader does not exist for declaration '$s' in 'predicate 'sv2.SV202_CompMedProcedId.get("SV202-02").Value >= 70010 && 
             ^

Comment: Is sv2 a property on the fact that you are trying to match? Also, can you please post the full condition as your are using it now?

Comment: I've edited my question with the details you need. Please let me know how to resolve this

Comment: In that case, remove the `sv2` from your condition to make it:

`$s : SV202_CompMedProcedId.get("SV202-02").Value >= '70010' && $s <= '76499' || 
    $s >= '76506' && $s <= '76999' || 
    $s >= '77001' && $s <= '77032' || 
    $s >= '77051' && $s <= '77059' || 
    $s >= '77071' && $s <= '77084' || 
    $s >= '77261' && $s <= '77999' || 
    $s >= '78000' && $s <= '79999'`

Answer (score 0):

If this is frequent enough you might write and import a static Java (!) function:

```
public boolean isInRanges( Comparable value, Comparable... bounds ){
    for( int i = 0; i < bounds.length; i += 2 ){
        if( bounds[i].compareTo(value) <= 0 &&
            value.compareTo(bounds[i+1]) <= 0 ) return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

The simple call is obvious.

You can't use a DRL function: AFAIK, the vararg notation isn't implemented (but check).